# Does from equivalent statements on inequality follow equality?

Tags: inequality

I have encountered a lemma where a number of statements of the form

1. $f(x) \leq a$
2. $g(x) \leq a$
3. $h(x) \leq a$

with $a \in \mathbb{N}$ are equivalent. If I choose $a$ such that $f(x) = a$. Then it seems that also the following statements are equivalent.

1. $f(x) = a$
2. $g(x) = a$
3. $h(x) = a$

This is because if $f(x) = a$ then $f(x) \leq a$ and $g(x) \leq a$. Assuming that $g(x) \not \geq a$, it follows that $g(x) \leq a-1$ and $f(x) \leq a-1$ which contradicts the proposition.

Is this reasoning correct and does this type of inference have a name as it seems quite general?

---

Update: In the original problem, $f,g,h$ are functions that compute parameters of graphs, e.g. the treewidth or the minimum of the maximum clique size of all triangulations. The problem seemed more general to me, however. Sorry, I don't have the mathematical knowledge to formulate the problem more precisely.

Comment: $a\in\Bbb N,$ but where do $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ belong to?

Comment: I think the argument makes sense, no matter what the domain of discourse is. If $f(x)=a$, but $g(x)\ne a$, then, since $g(x)\le a$, it follows that $g(x)=b$ for some $b<a$, but then $f(x)\le b$, so $f(x)<a$, contradiction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson your argument sounds perfect. And it is not domain-dependent like the OP's one (which, for its correctness, needed $f,g$ to be integer-valued).